# Any way to restrict permissions at the subsite in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a site collection and user A is having Design permissions in it.I created a subsite inheriting parent permissions and now I need to give just read permissions to user A in my subsite.

I have tried going to users and group of subsite ..created new group having read permissions and added that user into it...but its not working any idea ...how I can do this?

Comment: It's probably better to ask this on Super User.

Answer (score 3):

If the subsite is inheriting permissions, the user will inherit the design permission he has on the parent site.

You have to break the subsite inheritance (edit permissions) and then you can remove the users design permissions and add them to the Visitor group to give read access. Doing so in this way will not change the permissions on the parent site.